# Extract desired rows from file and write into another

Tags: perl

I have a tab-delimited file with following data. The first column represents an ID and second is the value for that ID.

```
294535  k__Bacteria  
294535  p__Firmicutes  
294535  c__Clostridia  
294535  o__Clostridiales  
294535  f__Lachnospiraceae  
537364  k__Bacteria  
537364  p__Planctomycetes  
537364  c__vadinHA49  
7652    k__Bacteria  
7652    p__Proteobacteria  
7652    c__Gammaproteobacteria   
7652    o__Thiotrichales  
7652    f__Thiotrichaceae  
7652    g__Leucothrix  
520836  k__Bacteria  
520836  p__Firmicutes  
520836  c__Clostridia  
520836  o__Clostridiales  
520836  f__Lachnospiraceae  
320231  k__Bacteria
```

I want the output in following format i.e. only the last two items from multiple items with the same ID.

```
294535  o__Clostridiales  
294535  f__Lachnospiraceae  
537364  p__Planctomycetes  
537364  c__vadinHA49  
7652    f__Thiotrichaceae  
7652    g__Leucothrix  
520836  o__Clostridiales  
520836  f__Lachnospiraceae
```

Can anyone help me with finding a good solution?

I have tried using an index and a `for` loop while reading the file line by line, but it's not happening. Here is my loop construct below which is not working.

```
while ( <TEMPIN> ) {

    chomp;
    my ($ID, $tax) = split('\t', $_);
    push (@taxID, $ID);
    push (@taxa, $tax);

    for ( $i, $i <= $#taxID, $i++ ) {

        if ( $taxID[$i] = $taxID[$i+1] ) {
            next unless $taxID[$i] != $taxID[$i+1];
        }
        else {
            print "$taxID[$i]\t$taxa[$i]\t$taxID[$i-1]\t$taxa[$i-1]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden in the unreadable string of characters?

Comment: Sorry was editing it! took a little longer

Comment: You only want the last two lines of groups starting with the same number? Have you tried anything yourself? Do you need an asnwer in perl or would you also accept other tools, like awk, sed, grep... ?

Comment: Where is the code which does not work?

Comment: What is the expected result when there is only one data within a group?

Comment: Yes this is the output I am getting after cleaning the file with unwanted data, this is my intermediate file from the original program. I don't need the program or answer immediately,  any guidance or idea and how to go about it will do too.. I think awk, sed can be integrated inside the perl program.. Anything would be good too.. After this I have to use the output of this and again write as tab delimitted

Comment: Read the file line by line and build up a data structure. Start with a hash, where the ID is the key, and the value is an array reference. For each line, push the current value to the array ref of that id's array ref in the data structure. When you're done, iterate the keys and print out zero or two rows depending on how many items there are in the array ref. You can access the last two elements with `$arr[-2]` and `-1`. If you need the IDs in the same order, keep an array for the order of the keys while building up the data structure.

Comment: @simbabque Hi, I have tried building hash structure initially, If you can refer to my code above I have tried to do  chomp;
        my ($ID, $tax) = split('\t', $_);
      $cleanTaxa{$ID} = $cleanTaxa{$taxa}; but unsuccessful

Comment: Let me try again accordingly @simbabque.. Thank You

Comment: No hash needed. Keep the last two lines, in alternatingly upated variables. Print them when the number changes. If single lines are possible input, verify before printing, that both stored numbers are identical.

Comment: @Yunnosch: There's no advantage to avoiding using a hash unless the data is enormous, and it makes the code much more complicated. And we haven't actually established that the input data is sorted.

Comment: @Borodin In my experience (which admittedly IS with huge data) it is always preferrable to write a filter with a scope of only a few lines, instead of reading all/most input in an then process. By the way my feeling (no proof) is that we are talking a potentially huge list of research data.

Comment: @Yunnosch: My experience tells me that the most important factor is that the code is clear and simple to read. What do you mean by *preferable*?

Comment: @Borodin I mean that processing huge data by looking at three lines at any time is more efficient and faster than reading all of it into memory and then produce output. That is what I call a filter. But as I said/admitted, this is based on the special scope of data I have experience with, which is huge. I agree with you, that readable code (which does not have any noticable disadvantages) is always to be preferred to unneccesarily optimised code. I should mention that I imagine (no quote, no proof) a three-line filter to be shorter and not less clearer/readable code. I might be wrong there.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I would consider that to be an *optimisation* which should be made only once the simplest and most obvious statement has been proven to be too slow and the program has been profiled to locate bottlenecks. A standard input / process / output flowpath is always more comprehensible, as well as being simpler to modify if the requirements change (see the OP's comment on my answer). I'm a firm believer that those of us who can do Fourier transforms in our heads really shouldn't expect to do so, and certainly shouldn't force others to follow along. Memory is far cheaper than development.

Answer (score 2):

This will do as you ask. It keeps a list of all values for each ID in hash `%data`, and maintains the original order of appearance of the IDs in `@ids` in case that matters

The output loop is just a matter of trimming all but the last two items from each entry and printing them

The program expects the path to the input file as a command-line parameter, and prints the output to `STDOUT`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my ( %data, @ids );

while ( <> ) {

    next unless /\S/;
    my ( $id, $val ) = split;

    push @ids, $id unless $data{$id};
    push @{ $data{$id} }, $val;
}

for my $id ( @ids ) {

    my $vals = $data{$id};
    splice @{$vals}, 0, -2;
    print "$id\t$_\n" for @{$vals};
}
```

#### output

```
294535  o__Clostridiales
294535  f__Lachnospiraceae
537364  p__Planctomycetes
537364  c__vadinHA49
7652    f__Thiotrichaceae
7652    g__Leucothrix
520836  o__Clostridiales
520836  f__Lachnospiraceae
320231  k__Bacteria
```

Comment: Hi,  Thank you for your very kind help. I was just curious what would one do in this case if he needs only 2nd last or 3rd last element from this hash array?

Comment: @Kanhu: That should be posted as a new question, but it's just a matter of changing the output `for` loop.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please explain this syntax @{$vals} and use of unless in your code please.

Comment: @Kanhu: `$vals` is a *reference* to an array, and `@{$vals}` (or just `@$vals`) is the array that it refers to. Take a look at [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). `unless` is exactly what it means in English. Essentially it is `if not`. Here I'm using it to save the ID in the array unless there's already an entry for it in the hash, i.e. it's been seen before.

Comment: Thank you very much it is pretty clear and understandable now.. I can implement and modify your code for further data processing and formatted output..